# How to correctly migrate from Firebird 2.5.1 to Firebird 3.0?

Tags: firebird, database-migration, firebird2.5, firebird-3.0

I'am trying to migrate Firebird 2.5.1 to Firebird 3.0
What is done:

1. Back up on Firebird 2.5.1
2. Restore on Firebird 3

The problem is that not all tables were migrated; procedures, triggers and views are not recovered.

Why? Is anywhere manual how to migrate correctly?

Comment: Backup and restore should work. If not, you might want to consider posting a bug on http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE. What commandline options did you use for backup and restore? Were there any errors in the output of either backup or restore? Are you sure you used the appropriate gbak version (the 2.5 version for backup and the 3.0 version for restore)? Have you also checked what happens if you backup and restore under 2.5.1 (or from 2.5.1 to - for example - 2.5.5). If all else fails, recreate the database structure and pump the data.

Comment: Maybe this will help http://www.firebirdnews.org/migration-guide-to-firebird-3/. Unfortunately it is not free. Yesterday I received the link an e-mail.

Comment: can you use ibeexpert, load sheme and all  data to  dml`s format on firebird 2.5 then using firebird 3.0 reconstruct your db?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I backed with gbak in Firebird 2.5 and then restored in Firebird 3 with -FIX_FSS_METADATA UTF8

```
gbak -c -v -user SYSDBA -password thepass /home/lbonomo/ssp.fdb.t.bk  localhost:ssp -FIX_FSS_METADATA UTF8
```